# How can I turn off gzip content encoding for IP from internal network?

Tags: nginx

I want to enable GZIP for the request from outside the network.

I tried config below in nginx.conf But I got "gzip" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:64 error

nginx.conf

```
http {
    geo $no_gzip_list {
       default         0;
       10.0.0.0/8      1;
       172.16.0.0/12   1;
       192.168.0.0/16  1;
    }
    gzip on;

    server {
        if ($no_gzip_list = 0) {
            gzip off; #<--Line 64
        }
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong? or How can I enable gzip for external request and disable gzip for internal request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official documentation says that you can use gzip inside "http, server, location, **if in location**".

```
Syntax: gzip on | off;
Default:    
gzip off;
Context:    http, server, location, if in location
```

So that means you have to move it inside location block.

Please look at example below:

```
http {

    geo $no_gzip_list {
       default         0;
       10.0.0.0/8      1;
       172.16.0.0/12   1;
       192.168.0.0/16  1;
    }

    gzip on;

    server {
        location / {
            ... # YOUR CODE

            if ($no_gzip_list) {
                gzip off;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!